# Function whose graph resembles the shape in this image

Tags: trigonometry, physics, chemistry

What is the function whose graph would resemble the shape found in the image below?

[image: EM spectrum]

I looked this up on Wikipedia, tried making my own, but I can't find an equation the Electromagnetic Spectrum. I think it's a sine function. Like sin(10<sup>x</sup>) or something.

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: That's just an artistic illustration of short and long wavelengths. It's not actually the waveform of the electromagnetic spectrum (whatever that might mean). Your guess isn't too far off from reproducing the look of the illustration, however: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sin%20%2810%5E-x%29%20for%20x%20=%20-2..-1

Comment: I have added a more precise inquiry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you're looking for is called a [chirp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp).